# AMPScript does not format the time properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a small script that adds 1 hour to a time string in sfmc:

```
%%[ 
var @textTime, @newTime, @finalTime
set @textTime = "07:30 PM" /* Example time: "7:30 PM" */  

set @newTime = DateAdd(DateParse(@textTime), 1, "H")

set @finalTime = FormatDate(@newTime, "h:mm tt")
]%%
```

The issue with the above script is:

-@newTime seems to return : `7/21/2023 8:30:00 PM`

but @finalTime returns : `8:07 PM`

The final value I expect is : `8:30 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference note from [FormatDate](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/) function.

> The format patterns are not case-sensitive, but they must be used in the correct pattern argument (for example, both mm and MM are date and time formats).

Therefore it didn't recognize your pattern and used `mm` as "month" instead of "minute".

Use [Format](https://ampscript.guide/format/) function should make it work:

```
%%[ 
var @textTime, @newTime, @finalTime
set @textTime = "07:30 PM" /* Example time: "7:30 PM" */  

set @newTime = DateAdd(DateParse(@textTime), 1, "H")

set @finalTime = Format(@newTime, "h:mm tt" )
]%%

%%=v(@newTime)=%%<br>
%%=v(@finalTime)=%%<br>
```

Output:

```
7/21/2023 8:30:00 PM
8:30 PM
```